# How can I specify factor choice in Variable Importance Chart?

Tags: r, random-forest

```
library(class)

fit <- rfsrc(as.factor(DEFAULT) ~ .,
             data = CD, 
             ntree = 1000, 
             importance = TRUE,
             nsplit = 5)

plot(fit)
```

I'm trying to code a variable importance chart from the `randomForestSRC` package. I want to get results for `All` only. I can't find anything online or within the manual that could help me achieve that as `All` isn't part of the variable itself.

[image]